# How can IRT-Models be understood in GLM/ SEM Framework? (Predict Learning with added Paradata-Covariates)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, references, structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics

I'll be working with data from an intelligent tutor system similar to one studied in the [KDD-Cup 2010 on student performance prediction](http://www.sigkdd.org/kdd-cup-2010-student-performance-evaluation) and plan to use IRT models to infer item and ability parameters. Other covariates such as 'number of attempts' or 'time spent on the problem' are readily available. I am interested in **incorporating these kind of covariates ('paradata')  in the estimation of the latent traits**.

Do you consider this a meaningful project, or do you expect that not much can be gained by including these additional variables? Are you aware of similar projects?

What would be a good place to *learn how to fit IRT models in the more general framework of GLMs/ SEMs?* [I have been pointed toward publications from Sophia Rabe-Hesketh and others](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/introduction-to-structural-equation-modeling?rq=1), but **ideally** I would be interested in  any **(online) resources or demos that are specific for a learning context and IRT**.

I currently have an alright understanding of IRT models, but don't have much experience in fitting them yet. So recommendations on R packages to work with in this context would also be appreciated. (I am aware of the psychometric task view on CRAN.)

Comment: Check out the book by DeBoeck & Wilson http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0387402756?pc_redir=1397798695&robot_redir=1 and this review on fitting models in R http://epub.wu.ac.at/4010/1/resrepIRThandbook.pdf Also, as you said, the work by Rabe-Hesketh http://www.gllamm.org/ and Bartholomew & Knott http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0470711108?pc_redir=1397026499&robot_redir=1

Comment: Lesa Hoffman of UNL has [some excellent PDF slides](http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/948/index.html) that consider IRT and SEM in turn and make some helpful effort to blur the line between them. In my limited experience, [lavaan](http://lavaan.ugent.be/) seems most versatile for working with thresholds in the context of SEM, but [the mirt package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/index.html) may approach SEM from the IRT side reasonably well too if you're not looking to do anything too intense.

Comment: Great comments! Here is another general reference, which explains some of the interest in [Mplus](https://www.statmodel.com/) for such approach: Muthén, B.O. (2002). [Beyond Sem: General Latent Variable Modeling](http://statmodel2.com/download/muthen1.pdf), *Behaviormetrika*, *29(1)*, 81-117. The https://www.statmodel.com/ website include additional links and resources.